# entire function problem in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

If f is an entire function satisfying f(z+1)=f(z) and f(z+i)=f(z) then f must be constant throughout the complex plane.
I would appreciate if someone helps me know how to prove the above statement.

Comment: Restrict to a fundamental domain, use compactness, then Liouville's.

Answer (score 2):

This function is bounded and entire, since is is both 1 and i periodic and continuous.  It is therefore constant.

Comment: How did you conclude that f is bounded?

Comment: This function is 1 and i periodic.  Its range is just its image of the square cornered by the $0$, $1$, $i$ and $1 + i$.  That square is compact, which gives you a bounded range. Now apply Liouville.